# Dexter "REQUEST_ONGOING" error in android

Tags: java, android, permissions, runtime-error, manifest

I am using Dexter v6.2.3 in my android studio to handle the permission for RECORD_AUDIO but getting an error in "withErrorListener" method. The error just says "REQUEST_ONGOING".
Please help me out from this error.

Here are my codes :

```
Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this).withPermission(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                showSpeechSheetDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                if (permissionDeniedResponse.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                    showCustomDialog("Permission Required", "Record audio permission required to use this feature. You can grant this permission in app settings.", "Cancel",
                            null, "Go to Settings", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                    intent.setData(uri);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
            }
        }).withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(DexterError dexterError) {
                Log.e("Dexter error", dexterError.toString());
            }
        }).check();
```

Here is the library implementation :

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
```

And this is the logcat :

```
2023-08-20 13:59:40.595  6153-6153  Dexter error            com.pratapbrothers.dotted.pizza      E  REQUEST_ONGOING
```

I have mentioned the permission also in Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Test this:
add `token?.continuePermissionRequest()` to `onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown`
like this:

```
override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                        permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                        token: PermissionToken?
                    ) {
                        token?.continuePermissionRequest()
                    }
```